# HTML / CSS centering controls to the screen

Tags: html, css, layout

I am pretty new to ASP.Net and anything really web development related. Watched a few videos and got the basic idea.

The issue I have now is that I would like to center my views to the center of the page.

So as an example, I create a new ASP.Net MVC project in vs2015. I create a new view and my view looks like this.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test Page";
}

<div>
   <button>Click me</button
</div>
```

I want the button to be in the center of the screen both horizontally and vertically. How do I achieve this?

I have looked all over the net and tried almost everything I could find but nothing seems to work.

Edit: Full credit to Luke who point me in the right direction.

In Site.css located in the Content folder I added the following.

```
.centerStuff {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

and now my view looks like this.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test Page";
}

<div class="centerStuff">
   <button>Click me</button
</div>
```

Comment: The technology you're looking for to control the style of your webpage is called [Cascading Style Sheets (CSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets).

Comment: Yeah I understand that but every CSS that people have suggested has done nothing. For example setting the button class to "centerAlign" and then in either the `site.css` or in a `<Style>` I do `.centerAlign { text-align: center; }` does nothing.

Comment: Set the width of your `div` to 100% `div { width: 100%; }` and your `text-align: center` will be more obvious

Comment: See https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ and http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/wzSmc/

Comment: This has nothing to do with C# or asp.net or mvc. This is a css thing.

Comment: @mmcrae Well as I stated I am new to all this so how am I suppose to know? How do I know that this cannot be achieve in code behind?

Comment: There is no code behind in MVC.  CSS should be used for styling page elements.

Comment: @Fran Sorry what I was referring to was `Controller code` when I meant code behind. I understand that its not code behind, my bad.

Comment: I would check out the Bootstrap guidlines since ASP.Net MVC ships with it. It will give you a better understanding of item placement via scaffolding. http://getbootstrap.com/css/ I would pay attention to the "grid" system.

Comment: @Gaz83 well now you know. Part of MVC is the separation of concerns. In the view, it's regular HTML and CSS - no code from the controller is going to directly style the elements. As others have said, I'd stick with core Bootstrap (row, col-sm-6, etc) classes and styling guidelines

Comment: @mmcrae thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify a height for the container.  Check this out:

```
body{
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
}
.full-height{
  text-align:center;
  display:table;
  height:300px;//this is just and example height
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.center{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
   height:100%;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="full-height">
    <div class="center">test</div>
  </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

To set the height of the the .full-height div, you will need to get height of the window via javascript, then set it like so (example below uses jQuery):

```
var winHeight = window.innerHeight;//gets height of window
$('.full-height').css('height':winHeight+'px');//sets the div height
```

hope this helps?